# Adding Decimal Numbers

Tags: c++, math

Adding decimal numbers were my exam question.
Our teacher said the right code is this (Look below), but it doesn't work what's the problem

This is the question: 9/10-11/12+13/14-15/16+....49/50 Write a c++ program to calculate this question

[image: sequence]

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    double x;
    int p = 1;
    double s = 0;
    for (x = 9.0; x < 49.0; x + 2.0)
    {
        s = s + x / (x + 1) * p;
    }
    p = -p;
    cout << "Total: " << s << endl;
}
```

Comment: `p = -p;` should be inside of the loop.

Comment: This code is prone to floating-point rounding error

Comment: @mch I tried but nothing changed

Comment: This code is seriously ill-formed. It has several flaws. I don't understand why they teach C++ for beginners in some schools. It seems that even the lecturer doesn't have an idea about writing proper C++ code.

Comment: @digito_evo so what should I do

Comment: @Ata İpek Edit your question and describe the problem and what was asked of you. The image you have attached is not showing anything (Ok it shows it but only when typed in the search bar of the browser).

Comment: @digito_evo I did

Comment: What value should be total in the end? 0?

Comment: @digito_evo do you *really* think the code is bad? I have seen people teaching ```#define int long long``` and ```signed main()```

Comment: @digito_evo note expression `ill-formed` has particular technical meaning. Can you pin point place where it is `ill-formed`? I do not see it! Code have some mistakes but it is not `ill-formed`.

Comment: @digito_evo I don't know the total answer, he didn't explain it

Comment: As a side note, it is dangerous to use for loops on floating-point numbers, as they don't always reflect the literal value (e.g. 0.1 is not exactly one tenth).

Comment: There are three mistakes in the code. If I am right, your task is to spot them.

Comment: @justANewbie Where are rounding error problem? If you think that `for (x = 9.0; x < 49.0; x + 2.0)` can have a rounding error issue, you are wrong: integers have **exact** representation in floating point values.

Comment: `x + 2.0` -> `x += 2.0`. `<49.0` => `<=49.0`. And `p = -p;` should be in the loop.

Comment: @prapin: large `int`s may fail to have an exact `float` representation (past `16777216`).

Comment: @YvesDaoust You are right. A problem which *isnt this problem* may have issues. This problem _does not have those issues_. Small integers (<= 2^22 approx) are _perfectly_ representable by a ieee754 float.

Comment: @MikeVine: as I said earlier, this is a comment on the side. IMO the OP should be aware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your code's first bug is that in the for-loop, you have typed `x + 2.0` which is not an assignment statement. So it really doesn't add **2** to the value of `x`. Instead, you have to write `x += 2.0`. And the second bug is that you have to place `p = -p;` inside the loop. Otherwise, it won't have any effects.

Now by fixing these two flaws it gives the result as `Total: -0.0447071` which is not correct and it should be **0.935293**. And the reason for that is that your for-loop iterates **19** times instead of **20** because you have forgotten to type `<=` instead of `<` in `x < 49.0;` and thus `x` is incremented up until **47.0** and not **49.0** so your loop doesn't add the last number to the sum.

Well, this may be what you want:

```
#include <iostream>

int main( )
{
    int sign { 1 };
    double sum { };

    for ( std::size_t x = 9; x <= 49; x += 2 )
    {
        std::clog << "sum == " << sum << '\n';
        // here you have to cast both x and x+1 to double
        sum += static_cast<double>( x ) / static_cast<double>( x + 1 ) * sign;
        sign = -sign;
    }

    std::cout << "\nTotal: " << sum << '\n';
}
```

Also, don't use anything except *integral* types for the initialization variable of a for-loop. For example, use `std::size_t` or `int` or `int64_t`, etc. based on your circumstances.

*The output*:

```
sum == 0
sum == 0.9
sum == -0.0166667
sum == 0.911905
sum == -0.0255952
sum == 0.918849
sum == -0.0311508
sum == 0.923395
sum == -0.0349387
sum == 0.9266
sum == -0.0376859
sum == 0.928981
sum == -0.0397693
sum == 0.930819
sum == -0.0414032
sum == 0.932281
sum == -0.042719
sum == 0.933471
sum == -0.0438013
sum == 0.93446
sum == -0.0447071

Total: 0.935293
```

As you can see, in this case after 20 iterations (because (49-9)/2 == **20**), the total/sum will be ***0.935293*** so I hope this is what your teacher had in his/her mind.

Comment: is my code worked? How did you run it, when I click run nothing happens, Nevermind I saw your code up there, but the teacher said, write the code like how I write. Your code is awesome btw

Comment: @Ata İpek I edited the answer. Read about the bugs present in your own code in the answer. You will understand why it didn't generate the expected result.

Comment: The iteration count is not wrong due to the floating-point type. It is wrong because of < instead of <= !

Comment: @Yves Daoust Yep. Gonna fix it.

Comment: @Ata İpek A part of my description was wrong and I fixed it. Read that paragraph again if you want to know the correct reason why your for-loop iterates 19 times instead of 20.

Comment: The answer can be expressed as `763/600-(H24-H12)/2`, where `Hn` denotes an Harmonic number.